# Is it too hard to work with a minified js file? Sample code included

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add another icon (which are used for dropdown menus) to the main navigation bar of a web interface. I don't have access to all the source files, but I think all I need to do is edit a js file and an .asp webpage template.

Anyway, a developer said that the min.js file that I need to edit is too hard to work with and needs the original unminified js file.

If all I am trying to do is replicate something already in the navigation bar i.e. an icon used for a dropdown menu, then doesn't it really just come down to copying/pasting some of the js code?

I have included a snippet of code from the js file. You can see that this is where you input the settings for the icons, such as which icon to use, name, section etc. This is obviously not the only part of code that you need in order to implement another dropdown menu in the navigation bar, but shouldn't adding another icon dropdown menu to the navigation bar be as simple as repeating the code that has already been used several times in the min.js file for the other dropdown menus in the navigation bar?

````
        L = navMiniModeThreshold,
        I = [{
            section: "UserTickets",
            permission: "tickets",
            text: "tickets",
            icon: "drafts",
            onNav: function(e) {
                return UpdateSection("UserTickets", e + "Management/Tickets/frmTickets.aspx?default=true", !0, !1), !1
            }
        }, {
            section: "UserLiveChatNew",
            permission: "chats",
            cssClass: "UserLiveChatIcon",
            text: "liveChat",
            icon: "forum",
            onNav: function(e) {
                return UpdateSection("UserLiveChatNew", e + "Management/Chat/frmClientChats.aspx", !0, !1), !1
            }
        }, {
            section: "UserCallLogs",
            permission: "callLogs",
            text: "callLogs",
            icon: "phone",
            onNav: function(e) {
                return UpdateSection("UserCallLogs", e + "Management/CallLogs/frmCallLogs.aspx?me=True&Outgoing=0", !0, !1), !1
            }
        }, {
            section: "Tasks",
            permission: "tasks",
            text: "tasks",
            icon: "book",
            onNav: function(e) {
                return UpdateSection("Tasks", e + "Management/Tasks/frmTasks.aspx?mode=0&taskstatusid=4&source=m&default=true", !0, !1), !1
```            }

```    D.fn.stTopNavBar = function(e) {
        return e = D.extend({}, t, e), this.each(function() {
            ! function(c, d) {
                var u = "stTopNavBar" + n++,
                    m = u + "_NavMenu",
                    o = u + "_NavMenuSelected",
                    i = u + "_QuickAddMenu",
                    r = u + "_DashboardMenu",
                    a = u + "_NotificationMenu",
                    s = u + "_QuickAddSelected",
                    l = u + "_AvatarMenu",
                    h = I[0],
                    p = c.attr("data-rootpath") || "/";

                function f() {
                    var e = D("<button class='hamburger'></button>");
                    return e.append("<i class='material-icons'>menu</i>"), D(window).width() < 1024 && (A = !1, e.addClass("collapsed"), D("#outer-left-panel").addClass("collapsed")), e.click(function(e) {
                        return D("body").trigger("nav:treeToggled", !A), !1
                    }), e
                }

                function v(t) {
                    var e = D("<button title='" + _.escape(d.translations[t.text]) + "' class='left-item'></button>");
                    return e.attr({
                        id: u + "_Section_" + t.section
                    }), t.cssClass && e.addClass(t.cssClass), e.click(function(e) {
                        return b(e, t)
                    }), e.append("<i class='material-icons'>" + t.icon + "</i>"), e.append("<span class='counter' style='display:none'></span>"), e
                }

                function g(e) {
                    var t = D("<button title='" + _.escape(d.translations[e.text]) + "' class='right-item'></button>").attr("id", a);
                    e.cssClass && t.addClass(e.cssClass), t.click(function() {
                        return e.onNav(p), !1
                    }), t.append("<i class='material-icons'>" + e.icon + "</i>");
                    var n = "function" == typeof e.getCounterVal ? e.getCounterVal() : 0;
                    return D("<span class='counter'></span>").toggle(0 < n).text(n).appendTo(t), t
```                }
````

Comment: What you've shown is not minified code.

Comment: It's crazy to expect someone to work with minified files in my opinion. Then again, if you don't have access to the original source that's another major problem entirely.

Comment: In general you're not meant to work with the minified version of a file. The minification is to reduce the file size as much as possible for faster delivery to the user.

Comment: I don't even understand what is minified about this js file. I have added more code to my question. What about this is minified?

Comment: Well, there was no whitespace reduction. But the code seems minified. No sane programmer would name his variables with only one letter.

Comment: If you're modifying minified files, the process that generates that minified file may  overwrite the changes you are trying to make when it when minification occurs again based on the original source. Are you sure that you're making changes in the right place for your source control system?

Comment: Also, show your developer some respect. If you disagree with them on something, try to listen to their (very likely valid) concerns instead of trying to prove them wrong on stackoverflow.

Comment: This developer isn't really much of a coder. They are implementing an WebRTC phone for me (they specialize in VOIP-related technologies) and I just think they don't know much about js or coding in general, because I don't know anything, but it seems like I can even understand where to make some of the edits to add another dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Many tools can unminify a js, but you'll loose the variable names if you don't have the map file. Which seems to me is what your code is, an unminified file.
Assuming there's no original source code, because there was no source control and original developer bailed and you only have what's in production. Then yes, small changes can be done to this version. It's harder to follow, so if your developer is not really a developer, give him some slack and either do trial and error or find a professional.